# Limitar caracteres de una consulta SQL

Tags: sql

alguien me puede ayudar estoy generando una consulta sql uno de los campos tiene 250 caracteres
en formato texto.
como hago para que cuando lo consulte el campo de la
(tabla x) me traiga los primeros 30 caracteres únicamente

Comment: ¿Cuál motor de base de datos utilizas? La sintaxis cambia entre uno y otro.

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que usar la función substring() y mandar como parámetro el nombre de la columna, primera posición y última posición.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non, porro.', 1, 30) AS ExtractString;
```

Resultado:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet co
```

Comment: Correcto con el Substring se puede conseguir eso en el lugar del "Lorem ipus..." pon tu campo y eso deberia de funcionar. Algo Asi  `SELECT SUBSTRING(campo, 1, 30) AS campo_cortado
FROM tabla_x;`

Answer (score 0):

también funciona utilizando left
ejemplo

```
select left(campo1,30)from tabla_x
```